# При регистрации сделать автоматически сгенерированный пароль

Tags: node.js

Есть сервер `node.js`. При регистрации автоматически сгенерировать пароль. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это задача клиента. Сервер никак не должен оперировать с голыми паролями, только с хэшами. В хроме сейчас, например, уже предлагается автоматически сгенерированный пароль при регистрации на каком-нить сайте. Для FF можно просто fallback придумать и всё.